# How to modify Chrome Extension, which authenticates every user through Google's OAuth 2?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am trying to modify a small thing from an extension. All I basically need to edit, is the selector they use. If their selector is `$("#firstDiv")` I need it to be `$("#secondDiv")`. It is really that simple.

I downloaded the CRX file, extracted it, made the edit, but when I go and install it in my browser, it asks me to authenticate with Google Authenticator. Just like it's supposed to do, as it uses oAuth 2. HOWEVER, once I log into my Google account, it will not "save" the login. Right after I log in and press Log In, the tab closes and launches the same login page again on another page.

Is it possible to change that somehow? I found a semi-workaround. If I install the extension, authenticate with Google, then go make my edit in the extension folder, it works perfectly. However, I cannot send it to someone else, because the `manifest.json` includes my authentication key (392 characters long).

How can I modify the extension to my needs? Is there something I need to know about Google OAuth?

EDIT: Okay, I cannot even download the .crx file directly from Google, unzip the file, then move the files into a new folder, and install that script. Exactly like it came from Google. Are their .crx files signed? Is it impossible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download the .crx file, extract it, edit it and install it, its extension id is changed from the original one(this is the reason you are getting login page again and again). Now, client id used in extension is valid for only the original extension id. Thats why when you install it from web store it works fine because it retains its original extension id.

**Solution :**

You must retain the original extension id to make it work. First download [crx](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) viewer(very helpful for extension developers)

After installing crx viewer, navigate to your extension from web store. You will notice a page action(icon at the end of url). Click it , then click view source. New tab will open, then press f12 and check the console, you will find a "key" value. Copy it. Now go to your extension page again and download the extension as zip(from crx). Extract it and open its manifest.json file and paste the "key" along with value.(This step is necessary to retain extension id). Now install the extension from chrome by enabling developer's mode and clicking load unpacked extension and selecting the extracted extension. It should work now

Comment: Okay that sounds like something that could work. If I then pack the folder into a ZIP and send it to a friend, would he be able to install it as well? Without logging into my Google account. Basically drag'n'drop and it will be installed.

Comment: Yes it would work as long as you use "key" along with its value inside the manifest file to retain its id. When your friend will install it, it will be installed with the original extension id.

Comment: Okay that sounds good! I have sent it to my friend so he can test it. It works fine for my PC, but let's see if it works on his. The key inside manifest.json should never be changed, right?

Comment: Yes key should not be changed

Comment: Okay. What is the difference between doing this and installing it, going to the extension folder, doing my edit, and send it to my friend?

Comment: Whenever you install any extension, it generates an id which remains same unless you remove it and again install it.For auth related tasks,you must be familiar with client id which is derived from extension id.Now if extension id is changed,you will need to change client id.Once you upload any extension to chrome store its extension id remains constant unless you manually install it (not from cws like you are doing).For this reason key field is necessary. There is no difference between the two methods.Only thing different is key field.

Comment: So what is wrong with my method, when I install the script, change it the way I want, then send it to my friends?

Comment: You are not providing the key field. So chrome generates the id automatically for you which mismatches with client id.

Comment: Chrome automatically sets the key when you install it though. The one I send to my friends contains the key, just as if I were to put it there manually.

Comment: If you provide the key then chrome derives id from key.Thats why key is necessary to keep the id constant.It should work on your friends pc

Comment: The version I sent him from when Chrome automatically set the key did not work. I'll let you know when I hear from him.

Comment: Hell yeah, Sid! It works wonderfully! He installed it and it works without a problem! Huge thank to you!