# Call Google Chrome extension function from any website, without modifying the extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a question a few minutes ago here: [How to modify Chrome Extension, which authenticates every user through Google's OAuth 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934540/how-to-modify-chrome-extension-which-authenticates-every-user-through-googles)

However, it seems like the CRX files are signed, which means **I cannot modify the extension**. However, I know exactly how the extension works. Basically I need to do call a function, while parsing it a string. Is that possible to do through my website? The function from the `background.js` could look like this:

```
function sendAlert(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

Is it possible to call `sendAlert()` from my website?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to directly access an extension from a web page.

A web page can *communicate* with an extension in two cases:

- the extension expects external connections via, for example,  [runtime.onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).
- the extension listens to DOM events of the page in its content script AND there's an event that triggers the behavior you need

Comment: That is unfortunate. So there is no way I can do this? Check out my other question too, if you have some idea about that as well.